# Aligning check box's next to text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my check boxes align and stack such as http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox for example.

The page that I'm working on is http://juniorgoldreport.com/landing-page/

I've tried to use `display: inline;` and `text-align: left;` as well as `float: left;`. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. The class `chk_bx` is there only because I was trying my best to try and target just that section of the form.

This is my html:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="form_jgrsh">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Please enter first name">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Please enter last name">
            <br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter email">
            <br><br>
            <div class="chk_bx">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub_list" value="SH">Subscribe me to Stockhouse
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub_list" value="JGR">Subscribe me to Junior Gold Report
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

css

```
#form_jgrsh {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}
#form_jgrsh .chk_bx{

}
#form_jgrsh input, textarea {
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.exc-form {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You know what's interesing is that if I just take your code you posted here and stick it in a fiddle, it works fine, but on your linked page, it doesn't. So it's something on that linked page that's messing with it.

Comment: Go to your landing page and inspect the element (checkbox) using Chrome and you see that the input is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `width:100%`. give `width` to `checkbox`

```css
#form_jgrsh {
 width:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:left;
}
#form_jgrsh .chk_bx{

}
#form_jgrsh input, textarea {
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.exc-form {
  text-align:center;
}

.chk_bx input {
  width:20px !important;
  }
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
            <fieldset>
            <div id="form_jgrsh">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Please enter first name">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Please enter last name">
            <br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter email">
            <br><br>
            <div class="chk_bx">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub_list" value="SH">Subscribe me to Stockhouse
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub_list" value="JGR">Subscribe me to Junior Gold Report
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: thank you  for the information, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line here:

```
// First line
#form_jgrsh input[type="text"], textarea {
    width:100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

You were setting all inputs to `width: 100%` which was pushing the text below the checkboxes. Only set it to to `type="text"` inputs.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xa5fv1p0/

Comment: I would up this comment, but I don't have enough rep. Thank you! I also had no idea you could do that with css, that is put a `[type="text"]` as you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have `width:100%` assigned to all input fields, which is causing the checkboxes to take up the entire width.

Assign a class to the checkboxes and overwrite the width attribute like so:

```
#form_jgrsh .checkbox {
  width: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yhc4rujh/